# Apple Watch - No Matching Provisionin Profiles Found

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, apple-watch

I'm trying to submit my app to the App Store. I succesfully created the .ipa file, but when I submit that file to the App Store this error comes up:

[image]

It's never been a problem for me to submit my app to the App Store. But I recently added to my project a new app and extension for the Apple Watch. And those 2 are now causing me trouble.

*Does anybody know how to solve this problem?*

Answer (score 0):

After you've updated the entitlements for the app in the developer console, you must regenerate the provisioning profile and use the newly generated profile in your build.

Comment: I just re-generated my provisioning profiles. And I've been doing so the last 3 days several times... Am I missing something? (thanks)